# Replace NULL Value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

how to find and replace empty rows when using this .....

```
$Qemaster="select * from emaster where `branch`='$bid' and `department`='$did' and `status`!='L'";
$Remaster=mysql_query($Qemaster);
while($Rowemaster=mysql_fetch_array($Remaster)){
    $empcode=$Rowemaster[id];
    $name=$Rowemaster[name];
    $Tleave=0;

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td rowspan='2'>".$name."</td>";
echo "<td>Leave</td>";

$Qlp="select * from lpsummary where ((`month` IN(04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12) and `year`='$year') or (`month` IN (01,02,03) and `year`='$Nyear')) and `empcode`='$empcode'";
$Rlp=mysql_query($Qlp);
$RRlp=mysql_num_rows($Rlp);
while($Rowlp=mysql_fetch_array($Rlp)){  

$leave=$Rowlp['leave'];
$Tleave=$Tleave+$leave;
if($leave==NULL){
    $Eleave='-';
}
else{
    $Eleave=$leave;
}
echo "<td>".$Eleave."</td>";
}
echo "<td><font color='red'>".$Tleave."</font></td>";
echo "<td><font color='green'>".substr(($Tleave/$RRlp),0,4)."</font></td>";
echo "<tr><td>Percentage</td>";
}
```

if there is an empty row ... i wanna to replace that as - instead of echo "".$Eleave."";

Comment: By learning how to use the [MySQL Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query.

Answer (score 3):

actually you can do that directly via query so you will not have any `IF-ELSE` condition in your php code.by using `COALESCE()`, eg

Also, make it a habit to specify column names, not by using `*`.

```
SELECT colnames,..., COALESCE(`leave`, '-') `Leave`
FROM   lpsummary
WHERE  .....
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  COALESCE(l.leave, '-') AS `LEAVE`
FROM    lpsummary l
WHERE   (
            (month IN(04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12) and year='$year') or 
            (month IN (01,02,03) and year='$Nyear')
        ) and empcode='$empcode'
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Very nice function, I had been under the impression they wanted to update the table as well ><

Comment: Thanks Mr.J W ..
Now my code looks like as 

    $Qlp="select leave,COALESCE(`leave`, '-') from lpsummary where ((`month` IN(04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12) and `year`='$year') or (`month` IN (01,02,03) and `year`='$Nyear')) and `empcode`='$empcode'";

But getting error as 

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in